# How to install Oracle WebLogic Server ( JAR file ) in Mac OS?

Tags: java, jar, weblogic, osx-yosemite

I understand perhaps it's not the right question to ask here, but, I really can't install Oracle WebLogic Server 12c (12.1.3) in Mac OS ( Yosemite ). I get the following error message :

***The Java JAR file “oepe-12.1.3-kepler-installer-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.jar” could not be launched. Click the console for possible error messages.***

I get the following information's about Java environment ( java -version) from the terminal:

*java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)*

## Solution

I get the solution for this problem. Just need to go in the folder containing the JAR file using terminal and run it from there:

java -jar oepe-12.1.3-kepler-installer-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.jar

It will take you through the installation procedure.

Comment: Anyone has experience with installing WebLogic in Mac OS please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and run

```
java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar
```

You should see this window open and then is just configuring your options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if you run the JAR file from the terminal, this is working.

Comment: If you consider solving your issue you might marked as solved (only if you consider, so other can benefit in case they look for an answer)

Comment: How to marked as solved ? I'm now going through using the WebLogic sever in Spring tool. I will write a small note about the entire process soon.

Comment: If you consider it was the correct answer just tick the response as answered